# Making multiple API pulls in Javascript with different URLs

Tags: javascript

I am trying to pull data from the same API, however the format is different for some of the information.

```
  const getPokemon = async id => {
    const url = `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${id}`;
    const res = await fetch(url);
    const pokemon = await res.json();
    createPokemonCard(pokemon);

  };
```

Some data is under a different URL string, [https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon-species/${id}/](https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon-species/$%7Bid%7D/) so I thought about making another variable with that API call called `getFlavor`.

```
const fetchPokemon = async () => {
    for (let i = 1; i<= dex_id; i++) {
      await getPokemon(i);
      await getFlavor(i);
    }
  };

  const getPokemon = async id => {
    const url = `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${id}`;
    const res = await fetch(url);
    const pokemon = await res.json();
    createPokemonCard(pokemon);

  };

  const getFlavor = async id => {
    const url = `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon-species/${id}/`;
    const res = await fetch(url);
    const flavor = await res.json();
  }

  fetchPokemon();
```

I want `flavor_text_entries` from the `getFlavor` variable, so I am trying to call it here:

```
const flavor_entry = flavor.flavor_text_entries;
```

However when I call `flavor_entry` it says that `flavor` is undefined. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In your `fetchPokemon()` method you haven't assigned the results of the two calls to a variable. The variables `flavor` and `pokemon` are scoped to the methods they're defined in respectively, so you can't access them outside of those methods.

Comment: But I can recall the pokemon variable with no problem.


const fetchPokemon = async () => {
    for (let i = 1; i<= dex_id; i++) {
      await getPokemon(i);
    }
  };

  const getPokemon = async id => {
    const url = `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${id}`;
    const res = await fetch(url);
    const pokemon = await res.json();
    createPokemonCard(pokemon);

  };

  /*const getFlavor = async id => {
    const url = `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon-species/${id}/`;
    const res = await fetch(url);
    const flavor = await res.json();
  } */

  fetchPokemon();